# How to get access to JS-functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have html:

```
<div id="test" onclick="test()">TEST</div>
```

Also I have main.js which is included in the file app.js

```
import "./main"
```

The file main.js contains a function:

```
function test() {
    alert('Test');
}
```

But when I click on the test block, I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function

Please tell me how to properly access functions using the attribute *onclick*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the function available to the global context like this:

```
window.test = function() {
    alert('Test');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Exposing to global scope via window property will work, but since you have the function in a module, just make an advantage of it. Directive `import` is meant to be used together with `export` one (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

app.js:

```
import { test } from "./main"
```

main.js:

```
export function test() {
    alert('Test');
}
```

What do we gain? test function doesn't pollute the global scope. It's isolated, but shared between `app.js` and `main.js`. However in your case you refer to the function from HTML, meaning addressing global scope. So to make it "best practice", you could do in app.js:

```
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", test, false);
```

and remove `onClick` in the HTML.